# Is mod_perl dead?

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl, mod-perl2

It's been a long while since [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) was really updated and seems like its development stoped at Apache 2.2. I've been waiting for it to become available for Apache 2.4 for now a very long while, but that hasn't happened yet.

I've been trying to find an updated answer (for 2014) about its current state but all I find is very old posts in forums and mailing lists.

Mod_perl has been really rock solid for me and my applications so far and my only complain is that I cannot move to Apache 2.4 yet. Keeps working great with Perl 5.20, which is the most recent Perl version at this moment.

So, I'm hoping someone informed or even involved reads this question here at StackOverflow:

**Is mod_perl development dead?**

Comment: Very very few people need/want Apache plugins written in Perl. Most people use mod_perl to provide a persistent Perl interpreter for their CGI scripts. If that's all you want, Fast CGI is simpler.

Comment: Did you contact the mod_perl mailing lists and ask this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of July 26, 2014, I don't believe mod_perl is dead. The mod_perl source code can be found at:

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/perl/modperl/trunk/

The source code revisions log shows [commits as recently as 6 weeks ago](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/perl/modperl/trunk/Makefile.PL?revision=1602105&view=markup) related to Apache 2.4.

In addition, the mod_perl users mailing list's archives can be found at:

- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-modperl/

Activity there appears to be very consistent with active usage, and the developer Steve Hay (to whom the commits above are attributed) [commented](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-modperl/201406.mbox/%3CCADED%3DK4ZtRgofAYqVHse1pnA_mJXfEVuo%2B7%2Bux6s-V%2BXJGC0WQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E) as recently as June 23, 2014, that they are very close to releasing version 2.0.9 with support for Apache 2.4.